# SteamCMD "Error! App '237410' state is 0x10502 after update job"

Tags: steam, linux, steamcmd

I should most likely contact Steam Support as well about this, but my hope is this will be an easy fix.

My friends and I recently purchased Insurgency, so, in an attempt to get a server running, I downloaded SteamCMD, set the installation directory, and ran

```
app_update 237410 -validate
```

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, SteamCMD failed to complete the download and gave me an error

```
 Error! App '237410' state is 0x10502 after update job
```

This was all done on my server machine which is currently running CentOS 6.5 64 bit. Does anyone know what would cause this error?

Comment: Check that you have enough disk space available for the files you're downloading. You can also try forcing the use of a single CPU core as follows; `taskset -c 0 app_update 237410 -validate` - failing that, Valve.

Answer (score 1):

"State 0x10502" is the AppState of the application, as is stored in the `appmanifest` files of installed Steam apps (in the steamapps folder of the Steam Library Folder where they are installed).

The status codes are unofficially defined at https://github.com/lutris/lutris/blob/master/docs/steam.rst, but are also in integer form whereas of course the above is in hex form (beginning with 0x); when converted it becomes `66818`. The AppState can be multiple status codes combined together using binary `|` (or), and in this case it seems to be the following combination:

- StateReconfiguring = 65536
- StateUpdateStarted =  1024
- StateUpdateRunning =   256
- StateUpdateRequired =    2

I don't know what Reconfiguring means, but the rest is saying that an update is required (UpdateRequired) has started being downloaded (UpdateStarted) and I think UpdateRunning would mean that it is currently being downloaded or is installing the update (although I think that installing the update would be the Staging and Committing statuses, based on how patching usually works).

If the download was not still being downloaded at this time this should not have happened AFAIK based on my own attempts to watch these files as things are happening in the Steam client (which SteamCmd is basically just a command-line version of), but I am just a nerd and not a real Valve employee and I could very easily be wrong.

Answer (score -3):

firewall + proxy is blocking you. By pass it.

Comment: What leads you to believe this is the issue?

Comment: Could you expand on your answer by explaing how you would *"By pass it."* or even why the firewall/proxy is doing the blocking in the first place?